# Why aren't jest expect functions available inside toMatchObject?

Tags: jestjs

For example:

```
duty.forEach((dutyItem) => {
        expect(dutyItem).toMatchObject({
            person_id: expect.any(Number),
            date: expect.any(String),
            uxdate: expect.any(Number),
            is_split: expect.any(Number),
            split_rest_hours: expect.any(Number),
            aircraft_type_id: expect.toMatch(new RegExp('[0-9]|null')),
            type: expect.any(String),
            status: expect.any(String),
            location_start: expect.any(String),
            start: expect.any(String),
            uxstart: expect.any(Number),
            location_end: expect.any(String),
            end: expect.any(String),
            uxend: expect.any(Number),
            duty_time: expect.any(Number),
            is_zulu: expect.any(Number),
            is_flight: expect.any(Number),
        });
    });
```

returns:

TypeError: expect.toMatch is not a function

Explicitly matching the property like:

aircraft_type_id: expect(dutyItem.aircraft_type_id).toMatch(..) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `expect` methods [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect). Note that there is no `expect.toMatch()`. The `.toMatch()` is a matcher function that can be used on the return value of `expect(value)` as in `expect('abc').toMatch('abc')`.

It looks like what you're trying to do is say for each `dutyItem` the `aircraft_type_id` matches a certain regex. But you're trying to use a matcher as a value in an object and that's not quite right. Instead you can use `expect.any(Number)` (or String if it can be a string) and have a second more explicit expect statement like this:

```js
duty.forEach((dutyItem)w => {
  const airVal = dutyItem.aircraft_type_id === null ? null : expect.any(Number);
  expect(dutyItem).toMatchObject({
    person_id: expect.any(Number),
    date: expect.any(String),
    uxdate: expect.any(Number),
    is_split: expect.any(Number),
    split_rest_hours: expect.any(Number),
    aircraft_type_id: airVal,
    type: expect.any(String),
    status: expect.any(String),
    location_start: expect.any(String),
    start: expect.any(String),
    uxstart: expect.any(Number),
    location_end: expect.any(String),
    end: expect.any(String),
    uxend: expect.any(Number),
    duty_time: expect.any(Number),
    is_zulu: expect.any(Number),
    is_flight: expect.any(Number),
  });
});
```

This allows the first match to check the structure of the whole `dutyItem` object, then do a more explicit test on the aircraft_type_id after.

A bit more detail on why what you tried didn't work... Consider the object you're asking `.toMatchObject` to compare with. If your code looks like this:

```js
const matchObj = {
  key: expect.any(String)
};
expect(obj).toMatchObject(matchObj);
```

This means you expect `obj.key` to match any string. But what is the value of `matchObj.key`?  It's not a function, it's a special object that Jest knows means "any string" and when it's comparing the actual value of `obj.key` it knows to just check it against any string.

If instead you had this (if it worked) then what would `matchObj.key` be?  It would be the return value of `.toMatch()`, which is probably `undefined` but in any case isn't a value that is useful during the `.toMatchObject()` function.

```js
const matchObj = {
  key: expect.toMatch(regex)   // key will be the return value of .toMatch
};
expect(obj).toMatchObject(matchObj);
```

Comment: Thanx very much.  Ultimately, I'm trying to match a regex here because aircraft_type_id returns Number | null.   Do you know how i can accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, change the any(Number) to .anything() in the matchObject call. That will pass the first check even if null. Then the 2nd expect can do the regex check. I exited my answer to do that.

Comment: .anything() won't match null or undefined

Comment: Ah right. Sorry. I adjusted the answer. You can build the match object to have an appropriate value for aircraft_type_id as shown

Comment: awesome. thank you